# Deploy Angular 6 app with component library

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-cli-v6

I built an Angular 6 app consisting of a library containing components that should be reused in the future and an app. I created everything using angular cli, so I have the default structure

```
my-app
 |
 +-projects
 |   |
 |   +-my-lib
 |      |
 |      +-src
 |      +-package.json
 |
 +-src
 +-package.json
```

To build the project, I first build the library using `ng build my-lib --prod` and then build the app using `ng build --prod`. Afterwards the dist directory looks like this

```
dist
 |
 +-my-app
 +-my-lib
```

My question is now how to deploy this to my server, so that the app has access to the library. Locally everything works, so should I just transfer the whole `dist` directory to my server as usual? 
Or should I publish the library to npm and add it as a regular dependency to my `package.json`. 
And if yes, how do I set this up to not interfere with local development, where I want to build against the library in the dist directory?

Comment: I would probably publish on npm, that way anyone can pull from npm. I think with angular 6 you can package now and publish easier, https://blog.angularindepth.com/creating-a-library-in-angular-6-part-2-6e2bc1e14121

or using an npm lib called ngpackagr

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-packagr

Comment: Yes it would be no problem, however I would have to add the library as a npm dependency to my package.json, which means that for local test builds it would also build against the npm version. I would have to have two package.json s then

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `my-app` build already contains `my-lib` library therefore it should be enough to deploy just `dist/my-app`.

As for publishing to npm it is really up to you.

For local development, you might consider using [`npm link`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link):

1. cd dist/my-lib
2. npm link
3. cd to/your/project/dir
4. npm link your-library-name (probably `my-lib`)

When you change the library and build again, there is no need to redo link, it will pickup new version.

However from my experience when you update or install other "regular" packages you must do the link again.

Comment: That would be great. I'll try to deploy the app itself. 
`npm link` is not necessary with the newest angular cli version. Adding the lib as a library to the `angular.json` is enough to build the whole project

Comment: finally had the chance to test this, and the library is indeed included in the my-app bundle. Thank you very much